# Play 2.4, Webjars not able to locate bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, webjars

I'm attempting to use the Play webjars helper according to the documentation here to load Bootstrap: http://www.webjars.org/documentation

However when requesting the page I'm getting the following exception:

```
[IllegalArgumentException: css/bootstrap.min.css could not be found. Make sure you've added the corresponding WebJar and please check for typos.]
```

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0-1",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.4",
...
)
```

routes

```
#WebJars wrapper
GET        /webjars/*file        controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

html

```
...
<link rel='stylesheet' href='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("css/bootstrap.min.css"))'>
...
```

This same html file also uses the webjars wrapper to locate require.min.js, which works without problem.

```
<script data-main="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/main.js")"
src="@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("require.min.js"))"></script>
```

If I instead load Bootstrap using Plays reverse routing like so, it works:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")'>
```

Any ideas why the webjars helper is unable to load Bootstrap, but is able to load require.min.js?

The easiest solution for now seems to be to ditch the webjars wrapper altogether, as it does not really seem to make it easier or more readable when loading resources.

Comment: Have you tried to leave out the css-path: `<link rel='stylesheet' href='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("bootstrap.min.css"))'>`? WebJars should search the directories anyway.

Comment: I have, unfortunately I get the same error

Comment: Did you restart the server after you added the dependency on `bootstrap`?  The [sample app](https://github.com/webjars/sample-play2) seems to be pretty similar to what you are doing and is working for me.  So maybe you can see if it works for you.  And if so, compare your app to that one.  If you discover an issue, please file it: https://github.com/webjars/webjars-play/issues

Comment: It was actually that easy! I guess using play a lot has make me so spoiled that restarted the server never occurred as an option for me :-) Thanks a lot!